# Inspection checklist for new android mobile devices

Tags: hardware, bugs, nexus-5

Many factory faults and bugs in an android device are discovered by the user long time after he/she receive it. Early discovering of faults/bugs in a device is needed when there is a short return period.

Is there any checklist of common hardware and software faults and bugs that could be inspected once the device is delivered?

I am interested in answers for Google/LG Nexus 5 ordered from Play Store, but general answers for android mobile devices could be also useful.